# Make Emacs eshell / echo newlines behave like in a regular terminal

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp, newline

I noticed that when you ask, say, `echo` to not output the trailing newline in an Emacs eshell, it still does add it.

For example, from Bash:

```
$ echo -n "a" | sha1sum 
86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8  -
```

From Emacs' eshell:

```
$ echo -n "a" | sha1sum 
3f786850e387550fdab836ed7e6dc881de23001b  -
```

The reason is that an additional byte is added:

From Bash:

```
$ echo -n "a" | wc -c
1
```

From eshell:

```
$ echo -n "a" | wc -c
2
```

And using hexdump, here's the output:

```
$ echo -n "a" | hexdump -C
00000000  61 0a                                             |a.|
```

I'm a bit puzzled by that finding: there's an `0a` (ASCII control code for "new line") added which shouldn't be there (the "-n" option passed to echo is supposed to not add the newline).

What kind of elisp configuration magic is needed so that Emacs' `eshell` doesn't add a newline before piping the output of echo to other commands?

*P.S: Emacs 24.3.50.1 on Debian Linux.*

Answer (score 2):

`eshell-echo` appears to invert the typical (sh/bash) meaning of `-n`, which is probably unfortunate. (FYI it does tell you this if you type `echo -h`.)

In addition, if `eshell-plain-echo-behavior` is non-`nil` it forces a newline onto the end of the arguments.

So you want that variable nil, and you want to use `echo` with no `-n` argument.